# Is there a non-technical reason for choosing a Syndication format?

Tags: rss, feed, syndication, atom-feed

I have a project that will need to be able to export data for feed readers. Is there a non-technical reason I should pick RSS over Atom, Atom over RSS, one of the flavors of RSS over another or anything else?

In particular, I'm looking for things like low or high adoption, difficulties/incompatibilities or particular ease with popular aggregators and the like. I've only recently begun using RSS on a daily basis in my own personal life. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://www.intertwingly.net/wiki/pie/Rss20AndAtom10Compared) should be *the* answer ;) About the only NON-technical reason which has forced one's choice that I've seen is: hey, [insert any famous netizen] uses RSS!

Comment: He did ask for NON technical reasons. That table is all of the technical differences.

Comment: 'difficulties/incompatibilities or particular ease with popular aggregators' -- is a technical reason IMO.

Comment: Guess that's true. The reason I specified non-technical was neither were so difficult that I couldn't support either one.

Answer (score 1):

RSS certainly has astronomical adoption rates compared to Atom, so if you're interested in being in the mainstream, I suggest providing an RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

- RSS is the most widely supported but sometimes the interpretation varies (When you generate a RSS with embeded HTML some readers will make it unreadable) but it was really an issue some years ago now it's nearly a non-issue.
- Atom is clearer in its specification of how to embed HTML and all readers that support it do it well. It is sometimes unsupported but again it's not a real issue since at least two years ago.

So most differences are slowly going away just choose the better lib in your language of choice. And if both are good, include both or roll a dice...

Answer (score 0):

I think RSS is definitely becoming the syndication style of choice. Out of the dozens of feeds that I browse personally I'd say less than 5 were atom feeds.